# SVG w/ linearGradient only displays when page reloads in a react Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, storybook

I have two icon compound components in my react storybook using `linearGradient` likeso:

```js
Icons.Facebook = function FacebookIcon() {
  return (
    <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="..." fill="url(#facebookGradient)"/>

      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="facebookGradient" x1="27.5" y1="2.49999" x2="1.04211" y2="4.16368" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <stop offset="0%" style={{ stopColor: "#5936E3" }} />
          
          <stop offset="100%" style={{ stopColor: "#6E56B5" }}/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  );
}

Icons.Instagram = function InstagramIcon() {
  return (
    <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="..." fill="url(#instagramGradient)"/>

      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="instagramGradient" x1="27.5" y1="2.49999" x2="1.04086" y2="4.15369" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <stop offset="0%" style={{ stopColor: "#5936E3" }} />

          <stop offset="100%" style={{ stopColor: "#6E56B5" }} />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  );
}
```

In my story, `Icons.stories.jsx`, I render them:

```js
const Template = (args) => (
  <Icons {...args}>
    <Icons.Facebook />
    <Icons.Instagram />
  </Icons>
);

export const AllIcons = Template.bind({});
AllIcons.args = {};
```

The issue I'm having with is that, these two Icons will only be visible after I reload the page. If I go to the canvas tab and back into the docs tab, they remain in the dom, but they are not visible. If I remove the `linearGradient` and just use a regular hex color or a color (like `red`), they show without a problem.

As you can see, the `id`s are not the same, I'm using proper syntax as I read on other posts and github issues, but I'm still not able to find a solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

hmm, it seems like when I moved the `<Icons.Facebook />` and `<Icons.Instagram />` into the `AllIcons` Template as part of the `children` args, the linearGradients and the svgs themselves did not disappear.

```js
const Template = (args) => (
  <Icons {...args}>
    {args.children}
  </Icons>
);

export const AllIcons = Template.bind({});
AllIcons.args = {
  children: (
    <>
      <Icons.Facebook />
      <Icons.Instagram />
    </>
  ),
};
```

Not sure what makes this different. Any explanations?